# Transforming uniform probability density function over unit disc from polar coordinates to cartesian coordinates

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value, transformation, marginal-probability

I need to solve the following exercise and I am not fully sure about my approach as the results seem odd and therefore would like some advise.

Given are uniform random distributions of an angle $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$ and radius $r \in [0,1]$, both independent. Calculated shall be the marginal pdfs of the according cartesian coordinates as well as their expectation and variance.

From my understanding the marginal pdfs in polar coordinates are $f(\theta)=\frac{1} {2\pi}$ for $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$ and $f(r)=1$ for $r\in [0,1]$ and therefore the joint pdf $f_{\theta r}=\frac{1} {2\pi}$ for $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$ and $r\in[0,1]$ and $0$ elsewhere. Based on the transformation $x=r\cdot cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\cdot sin(\theta)$ and their inverses $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\theta=\arctan(\frac{y} {x})$ the Jacobian calculates as $J=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$.

Finally, the joint pdf for x & y can be derived as
$$
f_{xy}(x, y)=f_{\theta r}(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}, \arctan(\frac{y} {x})\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\\
=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
$$
Based on this the marginal pdf for x can be calculated as
$$
f_x(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \,dy\\
=\frac{1}{4\pi}[log(\sqrt{1-x^2}+1)-log(1-\sqrt{1-x^2})]
$$
For the expectation this gives:
$$
E(x)=\int_{\infty}^{\infty}x \cdot f_x(x,y)\,dx=0
$$
For the variance I am struggling to compute it, but it should be
$$
Var(x)=E(x^2)-(E(x))^2=\int_{\infty}^{\infty}x^2 \cdot f_x(x,y)\,dx-0
$$

Comment: Deleted the part with the thrown ball as it is irrelevant to the question. The radius and the angle are polar coordinates which need to be transferred to cartesian coordinates. The intervals are now explicitly given.

Answer (score 1):

Believe you made an error with your marginal pdf for x. The results should be:
After substituting y for x tan⁡(u) your limits would change from 0 to  $\arctan⁡(\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}} {x}) $and you would be integrating
$$f_{X}(x)=\frac{1} {2\pi} \int_{0}^{\arctan⁡(\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}} {x})}\sec(u) \,du$$

which would result in:
$$f_{X}(x)=\frac{1} {2\pi} (log⁡(\tan⁡(u))+\sec⁡(\arctan⁡(u)))$$ to then be valuated at 0 and $\arctan⁡(\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}} {x})$

This should result in the marginal pdf
$$f_{X}(x)=\frac{1} {2\pi}  log(\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}+1} {x})$$